# 10 votes to delete a question?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

From what I read in on the help pages, I understood that there are 3 votes needed for deleting a *bad* question.

Yesterday I had the following scenario:

1. Found a low quality question that was voted with score `-15`.
2. Voted for delete. I got a JavaScript alert saying *10 votes remaining*  - or something like that.  There was one vote to delete already.
3. Looking today at the question, I see that there are only 3 people that voted for deleting and the question is deleted.

Why?

> [image]
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/q/25822129/1420197

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten tricked by that message myself...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have misunderstood what that counter means.

Given your 15k reputation, [you have up to 10 delete votes a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-de/105876#105876) (5 default plus 1 each for the 5k over 10k); e.g. you can vote on 10 different posts to delete.

The counter you see is telling you how many of those delete votes *you* have left, **not** how many votes are still to be cast to delete that post.

Comment: Ah... I see. However, wouldn't it be good to improve that message?

Comment: @IonicăBizău: when clicking *delete* the dialog asks you: *Vote to delete this post (x votes remaining)*. I think that is clear enough that it means *you'll use one of those x remaining votes*.